# How to align information correctly on screen as well as fix footer content

Tags: html, css

I am just a student, so please be mindful of that, I am trying my best to learn how to code.
I have to create a website as part of my project and I am just having an issue with the footer. The information does not seem to be aligning properly, all the information is stuck to the right side of the page and my things are not aligning themselves properly. I want the links under quick links to align directly and the white line to go underneath both the about and quick links section. I have tried to make rows, columns, I played with padding, margins, nothing is working so please if anyone can help me I would deeply appreciate it. I will attach my CSS and HTML just so you can see.

I will also attach an image so you get an idea of what it currently looks like:

[image]

```
<!-- Site footer -->
    <footer class="site-footer">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="footer column 1">
            <h6>About</h6>
            <p class="text-justify">Construction estimation is agreat company lol Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus consectetur recusandae perspiciatis repellendus iure vero error dignissimos officiis atque est libero neque soluta eum vel autem dolores, adipisci voluptatum quibusdam.</p>
          </div>

          <div class="footer column 2">
            <h6>Quick Links</h6>
            <div>
            <ul class="footer-links">
              <li><a href="/index.html">Home Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
  </div>
        <hr>
        <br><br><br>
            <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2021 All Rights Reserved by
         <a href="/index.html">Construction Estimation</a>
            </p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</footer>
```

```
.site-footer {
  background-color: #26272b;
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #737373;
}
.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
.site-footer h6 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.site-footer a {
  color: #737373;
}
.site-footer a:hover {
  color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.footer-links li {
  display: block;
}
.footer-links a {
  color: #737373;
}
.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

after suggestions, it looks like this, which is better, but still a smidge off

[image]

Comment: can you add an HTML/CSS snippet for better visualization ?

Comment: oh I thought I did, can you not see it?

Comment: No, you just added Screenshots

Comment: I'll do my best give me one second

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: Can you post all the code relative to the question? It looks like there is some css missing. In this way it is possible for others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thats all the code I have for it actually, I triple checked, maybe check now I just copy pasted it again incase I missed something the first time

Comment: Are you using some kind of css framework, like Bootstrap, etc.? If you do, can you post the version you are using? I can't reproduce the columns with the code you posted.

Comment: Hi, check out the demo here →→ https://jsfiddle.net/Divya_Patel/54yke0za/12

Comment: you are so cool oh my god thank you so much

Comment: It is better now, but it is still a little off, like the things are still stuck to the left hand side of page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try moving hr tag and copyright p tag out of the row div.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.column-1 {
  width: 60%;
}

.column-2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.site-footer {
  background-color: #26272b;
  padding: 45px 0 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 400px;
  line-height: 26px;
  color: #737373;
}

.site-footer hr {
  border-top-color: #bbb;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.site-footer hr.small {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.site-footer h6 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.site-footer a {
  color: #737373;
}

.site-footer a:hover {
  color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.footer-links li {
  display: block;
}

.footer-links a {
  color: #737373;
}

.footer-links a:active,
.footer-links a:focus,
.footer-links a:hover {
  color: teal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.footer-links.inline li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Site footer -->
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer column-1">
        <h6>About</h6>
        <p class="text-justify">Construction estimation is agreat company lol Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus consectetur recusandae perspiciatis repellendus iure vero error dignissimos officiis atque est libero neque soluta eum vel autem dolores, adipisci voluptatum quibusdam.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer column-2">
        <h6>Quick Links</h6>
        <div>
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2021 All Rights Reserved by
      <a href="/index.html">Construction Estimation</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

check out the [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Divya_Patel/54yke0za/12)

Comment: It works better, but it looks like this now (I edited the post)

Comment: Hi, can you please create a jsfiddle demo for the issue? I think those links are having some additional styling. And in my demo, it is displaying properly.

Comment: I think it might be the margins on my pages or something, I will fiddle around more with the earlier CSS. It is working in the demo properly, might be something hidden in my other files. Thank you so much for your help though, have a nice day/night

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a student I reindented correctly your code in the following block and added some questions to help you spot the problem and refactor your code yourself.
I strongly suggest you to always keep correct indentation in code, especially in HTML, since it helps spotting structure problems.

```
<!-- Site footer -->
<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="footer column 1">
        <h6>About</h6>
        <p class="text-justify">Construction estimation is agreat company lol Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus consectetur recusandae perspiciatis repellendus iure vero error dignissimos officiis atque est libero neque soluta eum vel autem dolores, adipisci voluptatum quibusdam.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="footer column 2">
        <h6>Quick Links</h6>
        <div>
          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="/index.html">Home Page</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- If the following blocks are inside column 2, can they go under both columns? -->
        <hr>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p class="copyright-text">Copyright &copy; 2021 All Rights Reserved by
          <a href="/index.html">Construction Estimation</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      </div> <!-- Where is the starting tag of this? -->
    </div> <!-- /row -->
  </div> <!-- /container -->
</footer>
```

Comment: thank you for doing that, I will try to figure it out...